# lodash apply gives me TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, lodash

I'm not sure whats the problem with lodash or it is my setup maybe. 
But I get the error **"TypeError: func.call is not a function"**
within the node_modules/lodash/_apply.js

And this breaks everything.

this is my package.json.

```
    {
  "name": "mpster2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "firebase": "^4.1.2",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.38.0",
    "mobx": "^3.1.14",
    "mobx-react": "^4.2.1",
    "npm": "^5.0.3",
    "payment": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.68.5",
    "stripe": "^4.22.0",
    "validator": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.0",
    "babel-core": "6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.1",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.33.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "jest": "20.0.3",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^4.2.13",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.5",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^3.0.0",
    "react-error-overlay": "^1.0.7",
    "style-loader": "0.17.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.9.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.8.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.5",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

My webpack config is the standard one from react create app, only that I use css-loader and style-loader to you use css modules.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'd need to look at the stack trace of the error to see what is calling Lodash. It seems likely that Lodash is expecting a callback somewhere, and the callback is not being passed.

Comment: some library calls it unfortunetly

Comment: As it is this question is unanswerable. If you post the stack trace, we can at least advise. If it is a library, is some of your code calling the library? Perhaps the library has a bug. There are lots of possibilities.